# How to retrieve picked files on app restart from Internal Stroage and show in Listview Builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter ,I am unable to read picked files everytime i restart my flutter app they're gone
For example if i pick an image or a pdf file and show in listview its fine.But when i restart app they're gone how to fix this ? Thanks

In short please refer me how to keep files in my flutter app.
Here is a short sample from my code

```
    Widget show({
    required List<PlatformFile> files,
  }) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: files.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final file = files[index];
        return buildFile(file, context);
      },
    );
  }
 Widget buildFile(PlatformFile file, BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print("File Path is ${file.path}");
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return OpenImage(pathPDF: file.path!);
                //open viewPDF page on click
              }));
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 150,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: (file.extension == 'jpg' ||
                        file.extension == 'jpeg' ||
                        file.extension == 'png')
                    ? Image.file(
                        File(file.path.toString()),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                title: Text(
                  '${file.name.substring(0, idx).trim()}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily,
                  ),
                ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: Are you storing the path of the saved files to the device?

Comment: Actually i am not.. how to do that can you help ..i am stuck very badly

Comment: I have shared you a sample code ..can you help on how can i save path?

Comment: Thanks, do you want to save all the paths or just the first one?

Comment: At first I will try saving the first file only and retrieve it back whenever i reopen app..Please tell me how can i save that file path after picking file in above code Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save and retrieve data from the device you can use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

You are saving the path of the first file correctly when picking the file, although you are missing the `await` on `prefs.setString("gotPath", file!.path.toString());`.

```
Future<void> readPath() async {
  final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final path = preferences.getString('gotPath');
}
```

In this way you can retrieve the path you saved to the device. Be careful as this function is asynchronous and thus you can use a future builder to wait on it.

Since you need to save the whole list of files to the device I am including an example on how you can do so by using `getStringList` and `setStringList`:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late final Future<void> _loadFileFuture = _loadFiles();

  Future<void> _loadFiles() async {
    final _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final _files = _prefs.getStringList('files');
  }

  Future<void> _saveFiles() async {
    final _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final _retrievedFiles =
        await _prefs.setStringList('files', _files);

    _files.addAll(_retrievedFiles);
  }

  final List<String> _files = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadFileFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          return ListView.builder();
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You .. but how to use this to retrieve file in ListView builder..can you explain?

Comment: Do you mean to retrieve all the files that were displayed in the list view?

Comment: Yes all those files which i once pick from phone ..restart the app and they should be there..how can i achieve this ?

Comment: I have edited my code you can check ..I am calling Widget show from child of build method and following is what i edited you can go through

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks i'll try it out and let u know

Comment: Can you help how to deal with pdf,word,other doc files ..I am making a document saver app like if i pick a doc or image from device and show in the app..it should be there on next restart..how to deal with this problem ?